# outlook email text into SharePoint field using UiPath

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I'm new to UiPath; however, by referring a online tutorial I was able to read the whole outlook email and forward this to other email ID.

Now my job is to, parse the test from the raw outlook email content and put the required text in the specific fields in a SharePoint site [site has text box already designed] and save this. Means, if a particular subject line (that contains string "Critical") is read from email should go to particular pre-defined text-box in the SharePoint. Hope my question is understood. How can I do this using UiPath or any other RPA tool? and tutorial or link would help.

Note: **The attached file is** ; now i'm able to read to content from the email. Please guide me how to put those extracted text/stings/values into specific SharePoint field? [Work done so far](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HqEuZy9LwVCgBnsHu_AGxM8SeY96zgNa) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the subject line can simply be done by using the `String.Contains` method (learn more about this one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Then, use control structures to act accordingly. Here's an example with `If`. Note that the subject's text is converted to lowercase first.

[image]

With regard to Sharepoint - you could either use custom activities from the [SharePoint Package](https://go.uipath.com/component/sharepoint-custom-activities-package), or simply rely on web automation and activities such as [Set Text](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/set-value) to populate parts of your page, or potentially create that page in the first place.